# Can we have bio.stackexchange.com as a redirect?

Tags: discussion, url

This might sound a bit peculiar, but I was wondering if it's possible to have http://bio.stackexchange.com to redirect to this site. I was thinking "BioStackExchange" sounds nice, and thought having that URL redirect here might be good...

Answer (score 4):

*Can* you have it? Sure.

*Should* you have it? Eh...

1. Are there any other meanings for "bio" that might cause conflicts in the future?
2. Do folks actually intend to *use* this? (yeah, it's less to type, but once you've typed biology.stackexchange.com a few times, your browser probably suggests it after "bio...")

Comment: If you foresee any new site with "bio", it is actually a pro for reserving it for this site...

Comment: I can't imagine any site for which "bio" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps a biographical site or bio-medical engineering could use it, but they would probably favor something more specific. It still seems like this site would be far more appropriate for the redirect though.

Comment: I agree that most people outside the field would probably think of _biography_ before _biology_ when confronted with _bio-_. Have a look at the google [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=bio) when searching for _bio_.